# How to disable PGN viewer showing "NN - NN"?

Tags: discussion, pgn-viewer

If nothing is put in for the title, the PGN viewer shows "NN - NN" as the title, which is confusing and distracting. How can this be suppressed by default?

```
[FEN ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to put `[Title ""]` as a PGN tag:

```
[FEN ""]
[Title ""]
```

Filling in the title causes a title bar to appear:

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Title"]
```